# Azure - mfa should be enabled accounts with write permissions on your subscription compliance

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication

In my azure environment under compliance i am getting this as incompliance. I tried navigating to MFA section but could not figure it out.

"mfa should be enabled accounts with write permissions on your subscription"

I am not sure how to enable multi factor authentication for write permissions.

How I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "mfa should be enabled accounts with write permissions on your subscription"

> I am not sure how to enable multi factor authentication for write permissions

As we have several ways to enable MFA, one of them we can make use of `conditional access policy`.

***Below are the common steps to enable MFA***

- After login to the Azure portal as an administrator (Global/Security)
- Select *`Azure Active Directory`* -> *`Security`* -> *`Conditional Access`*
- Select *`New Policy`*
- Select *`Users & Groups`* from *`Assignments`*

From here you can select the various options based on your requirement either it's for `write` permissions or `owner` permissions.

***Below is the screenshot from Azure Portal:***

[image]

As ***@Tim Beasley*** given the complete process here to [Enable MFA for write permissions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-cloud/security-control-enable-mfa/ba-p/1559110).